# The physics behind a "roly poly" toy

Tags: rotational-dynamics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, moment-of-inertia

[image]

What is the physics behind this toy?If we tilt it by any angle which force is causing it to come back?

Comment: In physics terms 'faster response' and sluggish response' are imprecise and somewhat vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the ballast weight at the bottom, the center of mass of the entire toy is below the center of the bottom sphere. When it is tilted over this causes its center of mass to be rotated upwards which causes the toy to be in an unbalanced condition. Gravity will cause the center of mass to again move to its lowest point, rotating the toy back to the upright position.

Comment: I did understand the concept but I am unable to answer the question....Can you please suggest the procedure to solve it through..?

Comment: the first two questions are associated with moments of inertia. the second two are conceptual questions associated with the condition i described above -- that the mass is always distributed such that it tips in the appropriate direction. consider the limiting case of fully tipped so both balls are tangent to ground.

Answer (score 1):

It is the force of gravity acting on the mass attached inside the lower sphere. When you tilt the toy, the mass is lifted off the ground:

[image]

However, due to gravity, it "wants" to go back down as far as possible – to the ground. So what happens is that the toy rotates such that the mass will eventually be in contact with the surface again.

Comment: then how are the mass of the balls affecting as asked in the question?

Comment: The mass of the structure is minimal compared to the "weight".

Answer (score 0):

Gravity -- the system effectively becomes a balance whose fulcrum is the point of contact between the bottom sphere and the ground. The weight is distributed such that it will always tend to tip in the direction of the weight/bottom, which in turn shifts the point of contact towards the weight/bottom of sphere.

Comment: So the side to which it is tilted the opposite side has mass distribution such that it brings the entire system towards its side....Am i right?
and this mass distribution should be directly proportional to volume or cube of radius??